# I got an issue with this form dropdown showing in the last input field. Solve the Css

Tags: dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor, cascadingdropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfTsN.png)

I want to give this input dropdown to background from CSS. I have an issue to giving the CSS in the background-color of dropdown.

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 search-col locationicon"><input type="text" id="locSearch" name="location" class="form-control locinput input-rel searchtag-input" placeholder="Where ?" value="" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-toggle="tooltipHover" title="" autocomplete="off" data-bs-original-title="Enter a city name OR a state name with the prefix &quot;area:&quot; like: area:State Name" aria-label="Enter a city name OR a state name with the prefix &quot;area:&quot; like: area:State Name" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0"></div>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand. It feels like English is not your first language. Maybe just clearly spell out what background color you want the dropdown to have, what background color you desire for the rest of page. And if you want to have any changes in those at what specific moments. CU and take care.